# Systemcalls that does not exist in systemcall table

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, fedora, system-calls, 32-bit

I traced some programs in Fedora 16 (32bit) with STrace and I'm writing some python scripts to parse the traces. I got all the system calls and their relevant number in fedora from 
arch/x86/include/asm/unistd_32.h

However in the end I found some systemcalls that does not exist in this table, and I'm wondering
1. how is it possible?
2. How should I assign a number to these systemcalls?

Here is a some of these systemcalls:

> set_th3_area  (set_thread_area)
>   socket (socketcall)
>   sendmsg (sendmmsg)
>   connect
>   bind (mbind)
>   getsocketname
>   sendto
>   recvmsg (recvmmsg)

Some of them have a similar system call in the table that I put in parentheses in the above list.

Update: I found that most of these exist in net/socket.c

> int sys_socketcall(int call, unsigned long *args)
>
> int sys_socket(int family, int type, int protocol) 
>   int sys_socketpair(int family, int type, int protocol, int usockvec[2])
>   ...

but I still have problems with assigning a number to these...
In the end I need a sequence of system call numbers

Answer (score 1):

I finally got the hold of the complete list of system calls from STrace source code!

http://sourceforge.net/p/strace/code/ci/master/tree/linux/i386/syscallent.h

This solved my issue. and one funny problem was that set_thread_area was first translated by the "read" in "thread" that was why I had set_th3_area.